# vtiger 5.2.1 on Fedora13

Tags: vtiger

Does anyone know if vtiger 5.2.1 works on Fedora 13? I only worked with vtiger on windows xp, and it seams that I have to migrate everything on linux, preferably Fedora. In vtiger's system requirements, it is mentioned only Fedora Core 6/9.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

vTiger should work on any platform supporting PHP. So yes, vTiger will run on Fedora 13 just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best platform is Ubuntu or Red Hat, i don't recommend to use OpenSuse.
With Fedora i haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

1. any system with apache, php and mysql is ok, even Mac!
2. We have lunched it (Vt 5.2.1) on CENTOS 5.5 X64_86 last year. That's great.
3. there is a picture depicting a working set measurements of this system in running state with a data base of ~10000 records: (linux command is : top -M)
   [image]

most of the times 1 GB of RAM is used (whole of the linux system) and bottleneck is mysqld service cpu usage!